# Custom Text on Product Page based on Shipping Class

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

We have multiple shipping classes, and based on each of the shipping classes we would like to display banner/text on the product page.

For example, in a case of free shipping, we would like to display something like "Free shipping on this item". And in a case of "flat Rate" - "Flat rate shipping $10", etc.

I was wondering if there is a plugin or a code that i could include in the functions.php to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Just tried to search for a code on internet. So far no luck.

Answer (score 2):

To display something above the product page, hook into `woocommerce_before_single_product`, and to get the shipping class use the `get_shipping_class()` method on the product, which can be retrieved with `wc_get_product()`:

```
function wpse_295878_shipping_banner() {
    $product = wc_get_product();

    $shipping_class = $product->get_shipping_class();

    switch ( $shipping_class ) {
        case 'free-shipping':
            echo '<div class="woocommerce-info">Free shipping on this item</div>';
            break;
        case 'flat-rate':
            echo '<div class="woocommerce-info">Flat rate shpping $10</div>';
            break;
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wpse_295878_shipping_banner', 20 );
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob for providing the code. Can this be placed within functions.php?

Comment: @DSingh Yes, place the code in your functions.php file.